# How to connect speakers onRaspberry Pi WH through PWM?

Tags: audio, pwm, speakers

Let's say I am trying to embed a Pi WH in my motorcycle helmet.   I need thin speakers just by the ear to hear sounds (so, I don't need them to be too loud).
* *by the way, piezo speakers won't do it in this project*

Since Pi WH doesn't have a 3.5mm audio jack, I think my choices are

1. use USB speakers
2. use PWM + audio amplifier + speakers

I can certainly buy a set of USB speakers and just connect to it, but the size matters.  so I am thinking #2 would only be my choice.

As far as I researched, I think this is the way to go.

1. setup `Option 1. Use Device Tree Overlay`
   https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-basic-audio-ouput-to-raspberry-pi-zero/pi-zero-pwm-audio
2. connect a [LM386 audio amplifier](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/LM386-Module-20-Times-Gain-Audio-Amplifier-Module-in-selling/32343485357.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.8.2cc34c6bm8h58A&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10151_10065_10344_5723115_10068_5722815_10342_10343_10340_5722915_10341_5722615_10696_10084_10083_10618_10307_5722715_10059_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_5722515_10621_10620,searchweb201603_50,ppcSwitch_7&algo_expid=60346333-5510-46dc-98e9-70989ca96496-1&algo_pvid=60346333-5510-46dc-98e9-70989ca96496&priceBeautifyAB=0) to one of the PWM pins

   - RPi 5v pin -> VCC
   - RPi ground -> GND
   - RPi a PWM pin  -> IN
   - RPi ground -> GND
3. connect speakers like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10722) to the audio amplifier
4. remove noises by [this config](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=195178) `audio_pwm_mode=2`
5. play sounds by `aplay` command

Please let me know if any of the steps are wrong before I go ahead and buy all of the parts.

---

**update**:

I did the followings to just make sure a speaker without an amplifier would sound just enough.. but I hear nothing coming out of the speaker, not even a noise.  It's complete silence.
**Anything I am missing or not doing right?**

1. add `dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4` to /boot/config.txt
   `dtparam=audio=on` is not commented
2. `sudo raspi-config` -> Advanced Options -> Audio -> Force 3.5mm ('headphone') jack
3. reboot
4. `gpio readall` shows
   `ALT5 | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18`
   and
   `|  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 | ALT0`
5. `alsamixer` and set the volume 100%
6. hooked a speaker like this (PWM0 = stereo right channel?)
7. `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Rear_Center.wav` or `mpg321 some.mp3`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For small speakers at low volumes, an audio amplifier may not be necessary. I've had success with PWM audio using the now-discontinued [CHIP](http://nextthing.co)
 computer (which should be similar to the Pi) and [these speakers from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1891) without an amplifier in between. If you happen to have the right parts lying around, I would suggest trying this setup before ordering the amplifier.

Also, I would be wary of using an amplifier from AliExpress; you might be better off with [this one from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1552). It uses less power, which could be useful for a project like yours. Also, it has both the L and R channel, so you could have stereo sound.